# how to remove a view in corona using its id?

Tags: coronasdk

I have multiple views create using a loop its a button and a textview actually, how do you remove one of them using id?

```
for i=1,#displaymovenames do
    moveButton = widget.newButton {
                default = "closeBox.png",
                over = "openBox.png",
                width = 50,
                height = 50,
                onRelease = startMove,
                id = moveID
                }
            moveButton.x = 50; moveButton.y = boxy

    local deletemove = widget.newButton{
        default = "remove.png",
        over = "removeOver.png",
        width = 30,
        height = 30,
        id = moveID,
        alpha = 0,
        onRelease = deleteSelectedItem
        }
    deletemove.x = _W + 20; deletemove.y = deletey

        t = display.newText(displaymovenames[i], 85, texty, native.systemFont , 13)
        t:setTextColor( 0, 0, 0)
        t.id = moveID

        boxy = boxy + 65
        texty = texty + 65
        deletey = deletey + 65
        moveID = moveID + 1
        moveitemscroll:insert ( moveButton )
        moveitemscroll:insert ( t )
        deletemoveGroup:insert ( deletemove )
end
```

well basically what this code does is that when the deletemove button is pressed the `moveButton`, `deletemove` and `t` are remove this is the function responsible for the remove:

```
deleteSelectedItem = function ( event )
   event.target:removeSelf()
end
```

as you can see I am only able to remove the view that is being pressed how about the other view that are being pressed? how can i remove them? can i use id right? if yes how?

## **Edit**

What i just wanted to do is this. Think of this items below as view.

```
  ------       -------------       -------
 |image1|     |anotherimage1|     |button1|
  ------       -------------       -------

  ------       -------------       -------
 |image2|     |anotherimage2|     |button2|
  ------       -------------       -------

  ------       -------------       -------
 |image3|     |anotherimage3|     |button3|
  ------       -------------       -------

  ------       -------------       -------
 |image4|     |anotherimage4|     |button4|
  ------       -------------       -------
```

when `button1` is press `button1, image1 and anotherimage1` is remove from the view and so on.

I can accomplish this if I just place them in a group the problem is that the buttons are already assigned to a different group. Is there any other way to solve this?

Comment: Sorry, I re-read your question many times, I believe the reply is probably simple, but I just cannot understand it! Can you attempt to improve your writing and explanation of what the code do?

Comment: sorry for my dumb question. please see the edited part. Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm not a fan of UI library, and I would probably use a table to store the buttons, but I think you can do this:

Inside the for loop:

```
deletemove.moveButton = moveButton
deletemove.t = t
```

The function:

```
deleteSelectedItem = function ( event )
   event.target.moveButton:removeSelf()
   event.target.t:removeSelf()
   event.target:removeSelf()
   -- remove listeners and nil the objects to avoid memory leaks.
end
```

Hope this works

Comment: How do you store this guys in a table? Can you give me any link that might help?